PBI Dax date difference ko
I have a visual in pbi with data coming from Factsales table.
In sales I have customer date + the date ids to dim_salesDate and dim_DeliverDate.
dim_salesDate is also link to factOrder.
I need to build a table with the customer date, date sales, date delivered(if it is) and the delay.
Delay is difference between sale date and today(if there is no delivered date).
e.g.

Paul 13/09/2024 null 2 days
Dan  13/09/2024 null       2 days(no
delivered date so use today 15/09)

CALCULATE(
DATEDIFF(MAX(dim_salesDate [Date]),TODAY(),DAY)
)

it does not work; I m supposed to have 2 rows in the table but I have a lot lot more.
It displays other customer rows with the same value 2, like it is doing cartesian product or don t know
If someone can help and explain why ?
Thanks

I think you have a problem with the row context and the relationship between your date tables and the fact one :
Delay = 
VAR SaleDate = MAX(dim_salesDate[Date])
VAR DeliveryDate = MAX(dim_DeliverDate[Date])
RETURN 
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(DeliveryDate)),
    DATEDIFF(SaleDate, DeliveryDate, DAY),
    DATEDIFF(SaleDate, TODAY(), DAY)
)

